# The etimology of the "-дцать" postfix?

Tags: этимология, числительные

For numbers between 10 and 40 Russians use дцать. What is дцать? A very Russian way to say десять? A word made of multiple parts, each of which do have a meaning, like дца and ть, as in еха-ть? (I would hope not!). I just cannot understand, where it comes from, as I cannot think of any words which have дцать, except for numbers in range from 10 to 40!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Более подробно разбиралось здесь: [Тридцать, сорок](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/9580/Тридцать-сорок)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Дцать" is just a reduction, originally "двенадцать" was "дъванадесѩте", sort of "two on top of ten". English word of Latin origin "decimal" can give you a hint.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!